# Proof of Cramér-Lundberg inequality

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

I'm trying to prove the Cramér-Lundberg inequality, which deals with the probability of ruin for an insurance company given a certain initial capital. Specifically, if $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots$ are the differences between the premiums and payments of an insurance company at time $n$, and $X_n = Y_1 + \cdots + Y_n$ is the total gain of the insurance company at time $n$, and $k_0$ is the initial capital, then the probability of eventual ruin $p(k_0)$ satisfies the Cramér-Lundberg inequality:
$$
p(k_0) := \mathbb P\left[ \inf\left\{ X_n + k_0 : n \in \mathbb N_0 \right\} < 0 \right] \leq \exp\left(\theta^* k_0\right)
$$
where $\theta^* < 0$ satisfies $\log\left( \mathbb E\left[ \exp(\theta^* Y_1 )\right]\right) = 0$.

My reference text proposes proving this in the following steps. Suppose $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots$ are i.i.d. integrable random variables that are not almost surely constant. Let $X_n = Y_1 + \cdots + Y_n$, and suppose there is $\delta > 0$ so that $\mathbb E\left[\exp\left(\theta Y_1 \right)\right] < \infty$ for all $\theta \in (-\delta, \delta)$. Define $\psi : (-\delta, \delta) \to \mathbb R$ by $$\psi(\theta) := \log \left(\mathbb E\left[\exp\left(\theta Y_1 \right)\right]\right)$$
and define the process $Z^\theta = \left(Z^\theta_n\right)_{n \geq 1}$ by $Z_n^\theta := \exp\left(\theta X_n - n\psi(\theta)\right)$. We are suggested to show the following:

1. $Z^\theta$ is a martingale for all $\theta \in (-\delta, \delta)$.
2. $\psi$ is strictly convex.
3. $\mathbb E\left[\sqrt{Z_n^\theta}\right] \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$ for $\theta \neq 0$.
4. $Z_n^\theta \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$ almost surely.
5. If $\mathbb E[Y_1] > 0$ and if $\psi(\theta) = 0$ has a nonzero solution $\theta^*$, then $\theta^* < 0$.
6. Prove that if such a $\theta^* < 0$ exists, and if $\mathbb E[Y_1] > 0$, then $p(k_0) \leq \exp\left(\theta^* k_0\right)$.

I've been able to show 1, 4 (from 3), and 5 (from 2). I'm close for 2 but having some trouble: we need to show $\psi(\lambda\theta + (1-\lambda)\phi) < \lambda \psi(\theta) + (1-\lambda)\psi(\phi)$ whenever $\theta \neq \phi$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$. Clearly we have $$\psi(\lambda\theta + (1-\lambda)\phi) = \log\mathbb E\left[ \exp\left(\lambda\theta Y_1 + (1-\lambda)\phi Y_1 \right)\right]$$ Meanwhile by Jensen's inequality and concavity of $x \mapsto x^\lambda$ for $0 < \lambda < 1$,
\begin{align*}
\lambda \psi(\theta) + (1-\lambda)\psi(\phi) &= \log \left( \mathbb E\left[\exp (\theta Y_1) \right]^\lambda\right) + \log\left(\mathbb E\left[ \exp(\phi Y_1)\right]^{1-\lambda}\right) \\
&\geq \log\left(\mathbb E\left[\exp\left(\lambda \theta Y_1\right)\right]\right) + \log\left(\mathbb E\left[\exp\left((1-\lambda)\phi Y_1\right)\right]\right) \\
&= \log\left(\mathbb E\left[\exp\left(\lambda \theta Y_1\right)\right]\mathbb E\left[\exp\left((1-\lambda)\phi Y_1\right)\right]\right).
\end{align*}
If I could show $\mathbb E\left[\exp\left(\lambda \theta Y_1\right)\right]\mathbb E\left[\exp\left((1-\lambda)\phi Y_1\right)\right] \geq \mathbb E\left[\exp\left(\lambda \theta Y_1\right)\exp\left((1-\lambda)\phi Y_1\right)\right]$,that would solve this problem, but this is very far from obvious to me (especially since the integrands aren't independent).

Then 3 and 6 I'm really stuck on. Any help on any of these three would be greatly appreciated. Note I would prefer not to use martingale convergence theorems because these results have yet to appear in my textbook; I can only work with square integrable martingales and stopping times.

Comment: How did you prove 4. from 3.? Did you try something similar to this my attempt https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4522743/use-of-fatous-lemma-to-prove-almost-everywhere-convergence? Thank you.

Comment: @Enrico this was a while ago and when I asked the question originally I hadn't worked it out completely, or I thought I did but was wrong in other ways. At the end of the day I didn't end up using 3; my strategy was more or less the same as gigaster's argument below.

Comment: Could you help with the proof of 5? I’m trying with the Jensen’s inequality for concave function but I’m not sure about it. Thanks.

Comment: @Enrico Jensen's inequality for *convex functions came into my proof; I used the strict convexity of $\psi$ and Jensen to derive a contradiction when $\mathbb E[Y_1] > 0$ and $\theta^* > 0$ satisfies $\psi(\theta^*) = 0$.

Comment: Uh! I used Jensen’s inequality with the $\log$ in this way: $\log(\exp(\theta Y_1))\geq \theta E(Y_1)$. In this way, given the positivity of the expected value of $Y_1$, only if $\theta < 0$ the function could be zero. Do I miss something?

Comment: @Enrico that was more or less what I did, but your inequality $\log(\exp(\theta Y_1)) \geq \theta \mathbb E[Y_1]$ is a little strange: this amounts to $\theta Y_1 \geq \theta \mathbb E[Y_1]$ (cancelling the log and exp), or $Y_1 \geq \mathbb E[Y_1]$, which is only true if $Y_1$ is constant.

Comment: @D Ford: sorry! I forgot the expectation inside the log! Does it make sense now? $\log(E(\exp(\theta Y_1))) \geq \theta E(Y_1)$

Comment: @Enrico ah yes in that case I agree completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are my ideas:

1. For point 2, I get by Hölder's inequality for the pair $(1/(1-\lambda), 1/\lambda)$ that
   \begin{align*} \psi(\lambda\theta+(1-\lambda)\phi)
   &=\log\left(\mathbb{E}\left[\exp(\lambda\theta Y_1)\exp((1-\lambda)\phi Y_1)\right]\right) \newline
   &\le\log\left({\mathbb{E}\left[\exp(\theta Y_1)\right]}^{\lambda}
   {\mathbb{E}\left[\exp(\phi Y_1)\right]}^{1-\lambda}\right)\newline
   &= \lambda \psi(\theta)+(1-\lambda)\psi(\phi)\;.
   \end{align*}
2. For point 3 we know that Jensen's inequality is strict, whenever the random variable in question is almost surely not constant, which is part of the assumptions. Hence,  using concavity of the square root we have
   \begin{align*}
   \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\frac{\theta}{2}Y_1\right)\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\sqrt{\exp\left(\theta Y_1\right)}\right]< \sqrt{\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\theta Y_1\right)\right]}\;.
   \end{align*}
   Hence by the independence of ${(Y_i)}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$
   \begin{align*}
   \mathbb{E}\left[\sqrt{Z_n^{\theta}}\right]
   &= \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\frac{\theta}{2} X_n - \frac{n}2 \psi(\theta)\right)\right] \newline
   &={\left(\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\frac{\theta}{2} Y_1-\frac12 \psi(\theta)\right)\right]\right)}^n\newline
   &={\underbrace{\left(\frac{\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\frac{\theta}{2} Y_1\right)\right]}{\sqrt{\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\theta Y_1\right)\right]}}\right)}_{<1}}^n\rightarrow 0\;.
   \end{align*}
3. In your question you write $\mathbb{N}_0$ which I assume are the natural numbers including $0$, but I am not sure what $X_0$ is, so I assume the process starts at $X_1$ and write $\mathbb{N}$. For $m\in \mathbb{N}$ define
   \begin{align*}
   \tau^{(m)}&:=\inf\{n\in\mathbb{N}:X_n< -k_0\}\wedge m\;,
   \end{align*}
   By construction we have $1=\mathbb{E}\left[Z_1^{\theta^*}\right]$. By point 1 we know that ${\{Z_n^{\theta^*}\}}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a martingale. Hence, by the optional sampling theorem we get
   \begin{align*}
   1=\mathbb{E}\left[Z_1^{\theta^*}\right]
   &=\mathbb{E}\left[Z^{\theta^*}_{\tau^{(m)}}\right]\\
   &\ge\mathbb{E}\left[Z^{\theta^*}_{\tau^{(m)}}\mathbf{1}_{\tau^{(m)}<m}\right]\\
   &\ge\exp\left(-\theta^* k_0\right)\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{1}_{\tau^{(m)}<m}\right]\\
   &=\exp\left(-\theta^* k_0\right)
   \mathbb{P}\underbrace{\left[\inf\{n\in\mathbb{N}:X_n+k_0< 0 \}<m\right]}_{A_m}\;,
   \end{align*}
   where in the second inequality we used that $\theta^*<0$.
   The only dependence on $m$ is in $A_m$, and since ${\{A_m\}}_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an increasing set of events you may take the limit and multiply with $\exp\left(\theta^*k_0\right)$ to get
   \begin{align*}
   \exp\left(\theta^* k_0\right)
   \le\mathbb{P}\left[\inf\{n\in\mathbb{N}:X_n+k_0< 0 \}<\infty\right]
   =\mathbb{P}\left[\inf\{X_n+k_0: n\in\mathbb{N} \}<0\right]
   \end{align*}
   which is the desired inequality.

Comment: First two points I agree with. Third I'm a bit confused; I'm not sure how you're defining $X_*$ since it seems to depend on $n$. Also, optional sampling is a theorem for (super)martingales, not submartingales, at least as I understand it; that's not a big problem because we can show $Z_n^{\theta^*}$ is a martingale (that's part 1 of this problem). You also need that $Z_n^{\theta^*}$ is a martingale to show that $\mathbb E[Z^{\theta^*}_n] = 1$ for all $n$. Also, given how you defined $\tau$, we don't know that $X_\tau \leq -k_0$, so I'm not sure about the inequality in your second display.

Comment: @DFord You are right, the proof of the third part was a mess, of course we know that $Z_n^{\theta^*}$ is a martingale. I sat down again and thought a bit about it and I think I fixed the third part. Do you think this might work?

Comment: Also there is a version of optional stopping for submartingales, where the inequality is just inverted w.r.t. the version for supermartingales (and maybe some additional conditions I forget here).

Comment: yes I agree with your revised proof. Thank you! I ended up doing it slightly differently (using optional stopping instead and a different set of stopping times) but yours seems much more direct.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea for the convergence results 3. and 4.

I will start with 4. : Write $Z_n^\theta=e^{n\big(\theta\frac{X_n}{n}-\psi(\theta)\big)}$ and let $A^\theta_n=\theta\frac{X_n}{n}-\psi(\theta)\;,n\in\mathbb{N}$. By the strong law of large numbers, it follows that for all $\theta\in(-\delta,\delta)$ $$A^\theta_n\underset{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow a(\theta):=\mathbb{E}[\theta \;Y_1]-\psi(\theta)\;\;\text{a.s.}$$  Now, observe that for all $\theta\neq0$
$$a(\theta)= \mathbb{E}[\theta\;Y_1]-\log \mathbb{E}[exp\{\theta\;Y_1\}]< 0$$ by strict convexity of the exponential (or Jensen). Thus, on an event $\tilde{\Omega}$ of probability $1$, there exists an $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ and $M<0$, such that for all $n\geq n_0$, 
$$A^\theta_n\leq M\;\;(on\;\tilde{\Omega})\;$$
Hence for $\theta\neq 0$ $$ |Z^\theta_n|\leq e^{nM}\longrightarrow 0\;\;a.s.$$ (For $\theta=1$, $Z_n^1=1$ for all $n$)

Finally, for 3. it suffices to use the continuity of the square root to conclude that $\sqrt{Z_n^\theta}$ converges to $0$ almost surely (provided that $\theta\neq 0$) and the Dominated convergence theorem to pass the limit inside the expectation.

Comment: You can prove 3 independently of 4 using convexity of $\psi$. It follows from independence of the $Y_n$ that $\mathbb E[\sqrt{Z_n^{\theta}}]= \exp(n(-\frac 1 2 \psi(\theta) + \psi(\theta/2)))$, and since $\psi$ is strictly convex by part 2, $\frac 1 2 \psi(\theta) > \psi(\theta/2)$.