# Use of Fatou's lemma to prove almost everywhere convergence

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I was trying to solve point 4. of this question based on an excercise taken from Probability Theory by A. Klenke (3rd version). Here is the link for completeness, but you can continue without reading as I am reporting here the main features below: [Proof of Cramér-Lundberg inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3166722/proof-of-cram%C3%A9r-lundberg-inequality)

I am not sure about my use of Fatou's lemma to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n=0$ a.e.

Let $f_n$ be a positive function (like $Z^\theta_n$ of the exercise in the link). We know that $\lim_{n\to\infty} E[\sqrt{f_n}]=0$ (also in the exercise). Moreover, $f_n$ is a martingale (as suggested by @jakobdt)

Using the Fatou's lemma and the hypothesis about the expected value in the last equality I get:

$0\leq\int \liminf_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{f_n} d\mu\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int \sqrt{f_n}d\mu=0$.

So from $\int \liminf_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{f_n} d\mu = 0$ follows that $\liminf_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{f_n}=0 $ and that $\liminf_{n\to\infty}f_n=0$ a.e.

Up to this point, is it right? How can I continue to show $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n=0$ a.e.?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: I see that $(Z_n^\theta)$ in the link is a martingale. This is useful.

Comment: Could you articulate a little bit more? Thank you.

Comment: If $(f_n)$ is a martingale then $(\sqrt{f_n})$ is a uniformly integrable supermartingale. So it converges a.s. and in $L^1$ to some random variable $f$.

Comment: I am new to these arguments. How is related the convergence a.e. of $f_n$ to that of a supermartingale? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I just posted a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $(f_n)$ is a martingale we know that $(\sqrt{f_n})$ is a supermartingale (concave transformation of a martingale). Since $\sup_{n}E[(\sqrt{f_n})^-]=0<\infty$ [we know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems) that $\sqrt{f_n}$ converges almost surely to some limit $g$. You already know that $E[\sqrt{f_n}]\to0$, i.e. that $\sqrt{f_n}\to0$ in $L^1$. Hence, $g=0$ almost surely. We conclude that $f_n=(\sqrt{f_n})^2\to0$ almost surely.

Comment: Very clear. One question: I can’t see how you determine that $g$ is zero a.e. from the $L^1$ convergence part. Could you explain? Thank you.

Comment: Since $g=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{f_n}$ a.s. we can use Fatou's Lemma to get $E[g]=E[\liminf_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{f_n}]\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}E[\sqrt{f_n}]=0$. Now we know that $g$ is a non-negative random variable with expectation $0$ so $g=0$ a.s. More generally, if $(X_n)$ is a sequence of random variables which converges almost surely to $X$ and in $L^p$ to $Y$ (for some $p\in(0,\infty)$) we have $X=Y$ almost surely. The proof of this is essentially the same.

Comment: Does the fact that $\sqrt{f_n}$ converge a.s. to $g$ implies that we can use $\liminf$, $\limsup$ and $\lim$ indistinctly? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Whenever a sequence of numbers $(a_n)$ has a limit we have $\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n$.

Comment: I am trying to prove your generalization @jakobdt, Does it require the $X_n$ to be non negative? I am writing this question to obatin a formal proof https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4523567/lp-and-almost-everywhere-convergence-prove-the-limiting-random-variable-is-t.  Thank you.

Comment: No, it does not. $X_n$ can even be complex if you want. If $X$ is the a.s. limit and $Y$ is the $L^p$ limit then I suggest looking at $E[|X-Y|]$ and writing $X$ as $\liminf_{n\to\infty}X_n$.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is not true in general. For a counterexample, consider the sequence of functions $f_n : [0, 1]\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f_1=\boldsymbol{1}_{[0, 1]}, \quad f_2=\boldsymbol{1}_{[0,1/2]},\quad f_3=\boldsymbol{1}_{[1/2, 1]}, \quad f_4 =\boldsymbol{1}_{[0, 1/3]}, \quad f_5 =\boldsymbol{1}_{[1/3, 2/3]}, \quad f_6=\boldsymbol{1}_{[2/3, 1]}$$
and so on. See that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}(f_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}\left(\sqrt{f_n}\right)=0$$
but $\forall x\in[0,1]$, $f_n(x)$ does not converge (so it actually converges nowhere, not just not almost everywhere).

Edit: I will do a quick edit to help OP finish the argument.

In the case that $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a martingale (MG) then $\mathbb{E}\left(\sqrt{f_n}\right)\to0$ does imply that $f_n\overset{\text{a.s.}}{\to}0$ as $n\to\infty$. For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $$\mathbb{E}\left(\sqrt{f_{n+1}} \middle|f_n,\dots,f_1\right)\le \sqrt{\mathbb{E}\left(f_{n+1} \middle|f_n,\dots,f_1\right)}=\sqrt{f_n}$$
where we used Jensen's inequality for concave functions and the MG property. Thus $\{\sqrt{f_n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a super-martingale (superMG). Since $\mathbb{E}\left(\sqrt{f_n}\right)\ge 0$, it follows that $$\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{E}\left|\sqrt{f_n}\right|=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{E}\left(\sqrt{f_n}\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\sqrt{f_1}\right)<\infty$$
Using the superMG convergence theorem, there exists an integrable function $f$ such that $\sqrt{f_n}\overset{\text{a.s.}}{\to}f$ as $n\to\infty$. Using Fatou's lemma and the argument made by OP,
$$f=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{f_n}\overset{\text{a.s.}}{=}0$$
and thus $f=0$ almost surely. Therefore, $f_n\to0$ almost surely as $n\to\infty$ as well.

Comment: Are you saying that the information about $\lim_{n\to\infty}E[\sqrt{f_n}]=0$ is irrelevant to determine the convergence of $f_n$? So I must find another way to prove it. Thank you.

Comment: Its insufficient, not irrelevant.

Comment: It does suffice to determine the limit infimum only, as I did, right? Thank you.

Comment: I've just edited to add some details to finish the proof

Comment: I think the direction of the Jensen’s inequality is wrong.

Comment: We are using concave functions, not convex. Thus the inequality is reversed.

Comment: I get that but you wrote, simplifying a bit, that $E[\sqrt{f_n}] \geq \sqrt{E[f_n]}$. This is the inqeuality for a convex function applied to $f_n$.

Comment: Ah I see. My bad, I shall edit my answer. Thank you

Comment: Does the fact that $\sqrt{f_n} \to f$ almost surely  as $n \to \infty$ implies that $\liminf = \limsup = \lim$ so it is sufficient to check only one of them to determine to what it converges? Thank you.

Comment: Yes thats correct