# $L^p$ and almost everywhere convergence: prove the limiting random variable is the same

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

If $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables which converge almost surely to $X$ and in $L^p$ to $Y$ (for some $p\in(0,\infty))$ we have $X=Y$ almost surely.

This was posted as a comment by @jakobdt to a my previuos question ([Use of Fatou's lemma to prove almost everywhere convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4522743/use-of-fatous-lemma-to-prove-almost-everywhere-convergence))

Here my attempt to prove it in the case $p=1$ for simplicity.

If $X \geq Y$:

$0=E[0]=E[\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n-X] = E[\liminf_{n \to \infty} X_n-X]\leq E[\liminf_{n \to \infty} X_n-Y] \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} E[X_n-Y] \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} E[|X_n-Y|] = \lim_{n \to \infty} E[|X_n-Y|]=0$

How can I conclude the proof? I know that if a positive random variable has expectation zero is equivalent to it being zero a.s.

Thank you.

Comment: The usual proof of this statement exploits the fact that convergence in $L^p$ implies convergence a.e. up to a subsequence. You realize this is true while proving the completeness of $L^p$.

Comment: In the meantime someone tries to prove it along my way, could you give me some references? Thank you.

Comment: Basically every real analysis textbook contains this proof. For example you can see Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis, Theorem 3.11 (with Theorem 3.12 being exactly this remark about a.e. convergence).